# some problem about to show imageView from CoreData in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, core-data

I saved the photo and name of the movie to `CoreData`. entity name is `movieEntity`

[image: 1]]

When I try to show a photo and name of a movie in `tableView`, I have a problem with the picture. The name of the movie successfully visible to tableView, but the photo of the movie is not visible.

```
class movieViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        var movie: [NSManagedObject] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self            
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
               super.viewWillAppear(animated)

               guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                   return
               }

               let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
               let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "movieEntity")

               do {
                   coreDataMoviePhoto = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
               } catch let error as NSError {
                   print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
               }
           }
    }

    extension movieViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return movie.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let movieData = movie[indexPath.row]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "movieTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! movieTableViewCell

            cell.tableViewCellImageView.image = movieData.value(forKeyPath: "img") as? UIImage
            cell.tableViewTextLabel.text = movieData.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String

            return cell
        }   
    }
```

here is `movieTableViewCell`

```
    class CoreDataWatchlistTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTextLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCellImageView: UIImageView!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saving image data not image in so use

```
if let data = movieData.value(forKeyPath: "img") as? Data{
   cell.tableViewCellImageView.image = UIImage(data:data)
}else{
cell.tableViewCellImageView.image = somePlaceholderImage
}
```

hope its help

Comment: `cell.tableViewCellImageView.image` It is not necessary in the first line, causing eror `Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type UIImage?`

Comment: Yes I removed that